# SublimeText3 Custom Formatting php arrays

Tags: php, arrays, sublimetext3, code-formatting

So I'm using SublimeText3 on Windows. I like to write my PHP to the PSR-2 coding standard.

However, SublimeText3 likes to do some horrible things with arrays by default.

What I want is this:

```
$fruit_colors = array(
    'apples'  => 'green',
    'bananas' => 'yellow',
    'oranges' => 'orange'
);
```

What Sublime does when I hit enter to go to a newline within an array:

```
$fruit_colors = array(
                     'apples'  => 'green',
                     'bananas' => 'yellow',
                     'oranges' => 'orange'
                     );
```

Pretty gross, right?

Also, I have the CodeFormatter package installed but it doesn't seem to give any way to fix this. Is there a file I can update a code template like in PHPStorm or Eclipse?

Also,  Re-indent doesn't work before anyone suggests that. Even if it did I don't want to have to run that every time I write an array.

This is becoming a deal breaker for me and Sublime. SublimeText2 never had this problem!

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Sublime is doing it the right way. scope should end where it started in general case.

Comment: I've never seen anyone's arrays in php written that way. Not in any framework, or CMS or open source project I've come across. I know braces should be on the same line but arrays and closures are different because they are contained in the variable. They're not control structures or functions.